# How do i change an AppBar theme using MaterialComponets parent syle

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styles, themes, appbar

@color/colorPrimary
        @color/colorPrimaryDark
        @color/colorAccent

```
<style name="AppThemeActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Custom.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Custom.ActionBar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <!-- Theme has both night and day modes**strong text**. -->
    <item name="background">@color/backgroundColor</item>
</style>
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to change, color of the app bar theme or removing it all together

Comment: What is the issue?